# Ubuntu 18.04 changed loading screen

Tags: gnome-3, ubuntu-18.04

Does anyone have any idea why the loading screen suddenly changed from this:

[image: ubuntu loading screen]

to this:
[image: New loading screen]

Also got some new backgrounds with the Debian logo like this one:
[image]

I would very much like to know what caused this and if it could have changed other system settings ( I noticed that the keyring doesn't ask me for a password anymore until I run an app on the computer and also noticed an overall slowness in running apps ). I want to point out that I didn't update nor upgraded the apt repos, I did however removed the ubuntu dock gnome shell extension and added plank, though this happened a few hours before and I rebooted twice in the meantime and the loading screen didn't change.

Comment: Hello, there's an Ubuntu SE place for these kind of questions instead of Stack Overflow: https://askubuntu.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second image is from [Ubuntu Budgie](https://ubuntubudgie.org/portfolio/screenshots).

How to Completely Uninstall / Remove Budgie Desktop:

1. To uninstall the desktop environment, open terminal and run command:

```
sudo apt remove budgie-desktop-environment budgie-desktop && sudo apt autoremove
```

And the PPA can be removed by going to System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Other Software tab.

2. To restore the default login screen (Unity Greeter), run command to remove GTK greeter:

```
sudo apt remove lightdm-gtk-greeter && sudo apt autoremove
```

3. To restore the default start-up splash logo, run command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

Type the number that indicates Ubuntu logo and hit enter.
Set Plymouth theme

And apply the plymouth changes via command:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Taken from: http://tipsonubuntu.com/2016/11/09/install-budgie-desktop-ubuntu-16-04-16-10/